# How to install reCaptcha in yii on a live server

Tags: yii, yii2, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate reCaptcha in a yii installation on live server. Following is the tutorial.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-add-google-recaptcha-in-yii2/

I'm not expert in yii so I'm lost. From which directory to run this command?

```
composer require --prefer-dist "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" "*"
```

Following are directories:
- backend
- common
- console
- frontend
- pjcms
- vendor

Comment: From directory where you have `composer.json` file. And you probably should not do this on production server.

Comment: I don't have local setup. Is there any other way I can install this package manually directly on live server?

Comment: You *can* install it directly on server, it just can break some things and usually you don't want to take down your production app by making some live testing.

Comment: Ok got it. Tx for clarification.

Comment: How to install a manually.>